# Ordered Vectors Form a Subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

I encountered a paper that claims that the set $S=\{(x_1, \dots, x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n: x_1\leq x_2\leq\dots \leq x_n\}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$. They do not make any further assumptions (e.g. equivalent under reordering.) They also do not claim to be in any [ordered vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_vector_space).

To me this seems OBVIOUSLY false based on the typical linear algebra subspace test: Let $n=3$ and $w=(1,2,2)$. Clearly $-w$ is not in $S$. Am I missing something?

Comment: You're correct, it's definitely not a subspace. It is a cone, meaning that it's closed under nonnegative linear combinations. Perhaps that's the property the paper uses and they just used the (very) wrong word?

Comment: @GregMartin It totally possible, but I am not exactly sure.. They claim that because it's a subspace, they can define an $(n-1)$ sphere contained entirely in $S$. I buy this for subspaces and can kind of convince myself for cones via a hand-waving compactness argument.

This I guess leads to the question: is it always true that we can find an $n-1$ dimensional sphere in an $n$ dimensional cone?

Comment: No proper subspace of $\Bbb R^n$ contains an $(n-1)$-dimensional sphere! so I sure hope they mean cone. Every open set in $\Bbb R^n$ contains an $(n-1)$-sphere, so in particular the interior of an $n$-dimensional cone will.

Comment: @GregMartin yeah it must be that they mean cone. With that the proof goes through just fine.